PowerShell problem with database restore, mdf file is claimed by another file. The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files
this is my script that I execute to restore database on remote sql server instance:
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, HelpMessage="Enter the SQL Server hostname. I.e 'plwron164\sql2014'")]
    [string]$sqlServerLocation,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, HelpMessage="Enter the location id custom database name")]
    [string]$locationId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, HelpMessage="Enter the path to the database backup file. Must be physical path to backup on server!")]
    [string]$backupPath
)
Import-Module .\modules\GenerateEnvironment\gecommon.psd1 -Force
InstallSqlServerModule
$newDbName = "DATABASE`_$locationId"
try {
    RemoveDbIfExists -sqlServerLocation $sqlServerLocation -locationId $locationId
    $server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $sqlServerLocation;
    $dbFiles = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServerLocation -Query "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='$backupPath';" -TrustServerCertificate
    $relocate = @()
    foreach($dbFile in $dbFiles) 
    {
        if($dbFile.Type -eq 'L') 
        {
            $newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultLog -ChildPath $newDbName) + '_log.ldf'
        } 
        else 
        {
            $newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultFile -ChildPath $newDbName) + '.mdf'
        }
        
        $relocate += New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile ($dbFile.LogicalName,$newfile)
    }

    WriteLog("Trying restore DB in $sqlServerLocation server with database name $newDbName...")
    Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServerLocation -Database $newDbName -BackupFile $backupPath -PassThru -RelocateFile $relocate
    WriteLog("Successfully restored DB") 
    WriteLog("Add for test user access to this DB")
    AddPermissionsForUser -sqlServerLocation $sqlServerLocation -locationId $locationId -user "USER_Test"

}
catch {
    WriteErrorLog("Error with restore db. Exception: $_")
    throw
}

and with line:
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServerLocation -Database $newDbName -BackupFile $backupPath -PassThru -RelocateFile $relocate

I am getting this error every single time when file is claimed by another file and can not be relocated:
Restore-SqlDatabase : Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: File 'I:\SQL2017\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\DATA\DATABASE.mdf' is claimed by 'DATABASE1'(3) and
'DATABASE2'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
what can I do to edit PowerShell script to relocate files that are claimed by another file?
If I do it in SSMS manually it works.

Did you read the docs for restore-database command or are you looking for "send me teh codez" answers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/restore-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps -RelocateFile argument looks promising

Are you trying add a new DB or replace an existing one? For the former use -RelocateFile for the latter use -ReplaceDatabase

@siggemannen oh... yes I have check it like I wrote above... I am executing this command with -RelocateFile and I'm getting this error mentioned, wihtout error I would not ask

@Charlieface I'm using command: Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServerLocation -Database $newDbName -BackupFile $backupPath -PassThru -RelocateFile $relocate
with -RelocateFile
and that causes my error, so there is my question how to avoid it

Hmm, sorry, i didn't see that, can you see what's the actual command that's being ran on the server?

Maybe output $newfile on each loop so you can see what's being used. Are you sure the path is valid? Perhaps you meant $newDbName = "DATABASE$locationId"

It looks like you've got multiple data files inside the database, but you're not accounting for the need for them all to have unique physical file names. SSMS handles this for you automatically which is why it works there.
As an example, I've created a database called Database like this:
CREATE DATABASE [database]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'database', FILENAME = N'D:\Data\database.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ),
( NAME = N'database2', FILENAME = N'D:\Data\database2.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ),
( NAME = N'database3', FILENAME = N'D:\Data\database3.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'database_log', FILENAME = N'F:\Log\database_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT, LEDGER = OFF

You can see I've got 3 data files. Using your script, $dbFiles gets populated by RESTORE FILELISTONLY and if I look at $dbFiles I can see those unique files:
LogicalName  PhysicalName            Type FileGroupName
-----------  ------------            ---- -------------
database     D:\Data\database.mdf    D    PRIMARY
database2    D:\Data\database2.ndf   D    PRIMARY
database3    D:\Data\database3.ndf   D    PRIMARY
database_log F:\Log\database_log.ldf L

Your foreach loop doesn't account for multiple data files, so $relocate retains unique logical names, but the data files are now all the exact same path, which is why you get the "claimed" message:
LogicalFileName PhysicalFileName
--------------- ----------------
database        D:\Data\DATABASE_2.mdf
database2       D:\Data\DATABASE_2.mdf
database3       D:\Data\DATABASE_2.mdf
database_log    F:\Log\DATABASE_2_log.ldf

As a quick fix, you can update the foreach section to something like this, where each iteration increments a number value to include in the file name (this also uses the source file extension rather than calling everything .mdf).
$relocate = @()
$l = 0 #log file number
$d = 0 #data file number
foreach($dbFile in $dbFiles) 
    {
        if($dbFile.Type -eq 'L') 
        {
            $l += 1
            $newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultLog -ChildPath $newDbName) + '_log_' + $l + (split-path $dbfile.physicalname -extension)
        } 
        else 
        {
            $d += 1
            $newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultFile -ChildPath $newDbName) + '_' + $d + (split-path $dbfile.physicalname -extension)
        }
        
        $relocate += New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile ($dbFile.LogicalName,$newfile)
    }

I now have unique names again. They are not a perfect match to the original, because this was just a fast fix, but it at least provides unique file names, allowing the restore to succeed. If you wanted to match the original more, you could add a little more logic to make that happen.
LogicalFileName PhysicalFileName
--------------- ----------------
database        D:\Data\DATABASE_2_1.mdf
database2       D:\Data\DATABASE_2_2.ndf
database3       D:\Data\DATABASE_2_3.ndf
database_log    F:\Log\DATABASE_2_log_1.ldf


and it work for you? With your code I'm getting this error:
Split-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'extension'.
because of line:
$newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultLog -ChildPath $newDbName) + 'log' + $l + (split-path $dbfile.physicalname -extension)

maybe you are using newer version of PowerShell than me, in my case I changed it to code below and it helped.
`
if($dbFile.Type -eq 'L')
{
$l += 1
$newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultLog -ChildPath $newDbName) + 'log' + $l + [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($dbfile.physicalname)
    } 
    else 
    {
        $d += 1
        $newfile = (Join-Path -Path $server.Settings.DefaultLog -ChildPath $newDbName) + $d + [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($dbfile.physicalname)

`

@kollodziej, sorry, yes, I'm on 7. I missed your 2.0 tag; I should have answered based on that. I'm glad you got something working though.

another problem after that if I tried to execute that again was that these files existed in that folder to relocate so PowerShell script failed. I added some check:
foreach ($relocatedFile in $relocate) {
    $filePath = $relocatedFile.PhysicalFileName
    if ($filePath -and (Test-Path $filePath)) {
        Write-Host "Usuwam plik $filePath, ponieważ już istnieje."
        Remove-Item $filePath -Force
    }
}

